# What to put in JDBC Driver Class when connecting JMeter with Azure Databricks cluster

Tags: jmeter, azure-databricks

What to put in JDBC driver class? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV1aE.png)

Little help I could find on internet so I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps my Internet is better than yours because I can find a little bit more "help".

In the [Configure the Databricks ODBC and JDBC drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi) documentation chapter I can see [JDBC Driver Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi#jdbc-driver-guide) section which looks like:

> For more information about the JDBC driver, refer to the installation and configuration guide. Find the Databricks JDBC driver installation and configuration guide in the `docs` directory of the driver package.

In the `docs` directory of the [downloaded JDBC Driver](https://www.databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download) there is `Databricks JDBC Driver Install and Configuration Guide.pdf` file.

In the `Registering the Connector Class` chapter of this file it suggests to use `com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver` as the classname

[image]

See [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter) article for more hints on database testing with JMeter.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I actually got one step closer to a resolution. Driver is funtional but now I am getting communication link failure error. Is it becuase of restrictions on the server?

"
Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([Databricks][DatabricksJDBCDriver](500593) Communication link failure. Failed to connect to server. Reason: HTTP Response code: 401, Error message: Unknown.)
"